# Allowing extension (beyond the crate) of implementation with event loop

Tags: rust

*Within* the crate we can happily do something like this:

```rust
mod boundary {
    pub struct EventLoop;
    
    impl EventLoop {
        pub fn run(&self) {
            for _ in 0..2 {
                self.handle("bundled");
                self.foo();
            }
        }
    
        pub fn handle(&self, message: &str) {
            println!("{} handling", message)
        }
    }
    
    pub trait EventLoopExtend {
        fn foo(&self);
    }
}

use boundary::EventLoopExtend;

impl EventLoopExtend for boundary::EventLoop {
    fn foo(&self) {
        self.handle("extended")
    }
}   

fn main() {
    let el = boundary::EventLoop{};
    el.run();
}
```

But if `mod boundary` were a crate boundary we get `error[E0117]: only traits defined in the current crate can be implemented for arbitrary types`.

I gather that a potential solution to this could be the [New Type idiom](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/generics/new_types.html), so something like this:

```rust
mod boundary {
    pub struct EventLoop;
    
    impl EventLoop {
        pub fn run(&self) {
            for _ in 0..2 {
                self.handle("bundled");
                self.foo();
            }
        }
    
        pub fn handle(&self, message: &str) {
            println!("{} handling", message)
        }
    }
    
    pub trait EventLoopExtend {
        fn foo(&self);
    }
    
    impl EventLoopExtend for EventLoop {
        fn foo(&self) {
            self.handle("unimplemented")
        }
    }
}

use boundary::{EventLoop, EventLoopExtend};

struct EventLoopNewType(EventLoop);

impl EventLoopExtend for EventLoopNewType {
    fn foo(&self) {
        self.0.handle("extended")
    }
}   

fn main() {
    let el = EventLoopNewType(EventLoop {});
    el.0.run();
}
```

But then the problem here is that the extended trait behaviour isn't accessible from the underlying `EventLoop instance`.

I'm still quite new to Rust, so I'm sure I'm missing something obvious, I wouldn't be surprised if I need to take a completely different approach.

Specifically in my case, the event loop is actually from [wgpu](https://github.com/gfx-rs/wgpu), and I'm curious if it's possible to build a library where end users can provide their own "render pass" stage.

Comment: If you define new traits or new type's they can newer be used in the underlying crate or module you refer to. Even when the methods are named the same, rust will see them as two different trait implementations. You can only use those abstractions in a crate or module you imported. What do you want to achieve? Do you just want to implement the underlying trait? Traits are usually used as parameters to functions or libraries to allow new behavior through the strategy pattern.

Comment: Thank you, you inspired me to dig deeper into the Strategy Pattern and found my solution :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @AlexN's comment I dug deeper into the Strategy Pattern and found a solution:

```rust
mod boundary {
    pub struct EventLoop<'a, T: EventLoopExtend> {
        extension: &'a T
    }
    
    impl<'a, T: EventLoopExtend> EventLoop<'a, T> {
        pub fn new(extension: &'a T) -> Self {
            Self { extension }
        }
        
        pub fn run(&self) {
            for _   in 0..2 {
                self.handle("bundled");
                self.extension.foo(self);
            }
        }
    
        pub fn handle(&self, message: &str) {
            println!("{} handling", message)
        }
    }
    
    pub trait EventLoopExtend {
        fn foo<T: EventLoopExtend>(&self, el: &EventLoop<T>) {
            el.handle("unimplemented")
        }
    }
}

use boundary::{EventLoop, EventLoopExtend};

struct EventLoopExtension;

impl EventLoopExtend for EventLoopExtension {
    fn foo<T: EventLoopExtend>(&self, el: &EventLoop<T>) {
        el.handle("extended")
    }
}   

fn main() {
    let el = EventLoop::new(&EventLoopExtension {});
    el.run();
}
```

The basic idea is to use generics with a trait bound. I think the first time I looked into this approach I was worried about type recursion. But it turns out passing the `EventLoop` object as an argument to `EventLoopExtend` trait methods is perfectly reasonable.